# Leaflet Circle is not saving to canvas image

Tags: javascript, leaflet, html2canvas

I am using Leaflet map and creating leaflet circle radius for 10,20 and 30 Km. the circle is created but i tried to save image for html2canvas function. so leaflet map (marker) only saved but circle is not saving the canvas image.

Leaflet circle function:

```
    circle3 = L.circle(pointA, ( 30 * 1000), { color: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.07 ,fill:false,weight: 2});
    circle2 = L.circle(pointA, ( 20 * 1000), { color: 'green', fillOpacity: 0.07 ,fill:false,weight: 2});
    circle1 = L.circle(pointA, ( 10 * 1000), { color: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.07 ,fill:false,weight: 2});

    circles.addLayer(circle3);
    circles.addLayer(circle2);
    circles.addLayer(circle1);
    map.addLayer(circles);
```

html2canvas function:

```
html2canvas($('#map'), {
            allowTaint : false,
            logging : true,
            taintTest: false,
            useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            //map.panBy([100, 100]);

            var dimensions = map.getSize();
            img.width = dimensions.x;
            img.height = dimensions.y;
            img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            sample3.innerHTML = '';
            sample3.appendChild(img);
        }
        });
```

Please help me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Be noted that `html2canvas` is not able to convert SVG by itself.

You should try setting the [`L_PREFER_CANVAS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global-l_prefer_canvas) global switch before loading Leaflet, so that your circles are rendered directly as a Canvas instead of SVG. Then `html2canvas` should be able to use them.

Otherwise, you could try to look for other posts about converting SVG into canvas before applying `html2canvas`.